# Oracle SQL PERCENT_RANK Skewed When Dupe Values?

Tags: sql, oracle

Good afternoon:  I'm trying to determine the best way to get a percent of products sold that make up 80% of sales cases (and/or dollars).  Last year, it was reported at 20%. I'm getting the same thing this year, but I'm apprehensive to believe that being that it appears to be a direct correlation between the percent of sales I need to the percent left over.  For example, if I want 90% of sales, then I get 10% of products.

Although the formulas seem to work in the query below, I'm wondering if it's skewed because of dupe values in the sales cases.  If I were to add up 80% of the sales cases, then the count of products is much lower. But I don't know if the query is skewed because of those dupes, and it gives me 80% at a higher value. I also saw that there's an aggregate percent_rank - should I be trying that one?

Here's an example of the query where I'm trying a couple of option to get to a more reasonable value. Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT
    sales_cases,
    total_sales_cases,
    total_item_count  ,
    NVL(RowNbrCs,0) as RowNbrCs,

    PERCENT_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY company_id  ORDER BY  (sales_cases / total_sales_cases) ASC )  as Rank_by_Cases ,
    PERCENT_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY company_id  ORDER BY   (NVL(RowNbrCs,0) / sum(total_sales_cases)) ASC )  as Rank_by_Cases 

FROM (
    SELECT
        company_id  ,
        prod_id ,
        SUM( NVL(sales_cases,0)) ,0)  as sales_cases,
        SUM( NVL(net_sales,0)) ,0)  as net_sales,
        ROUND( SUM(( SUM( NVL(sales_cases,0)) )) OVER(PARTITION BY company_id ),0)  as total_sales_cases,
        ROUND( SUM(( SUM( NVL(net_sales,0)) )) OVER(PARTITION BY company_id ),0)  as total_net_sales,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY company_id  ORDER BY  SUM( NVL(sales_cases,0)) ASC ) as   RowNbrCs,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY case when company_id  ORDER BY  SUM( NVL(net_sales,0)) ASC ) as   RowNbrSls,
        SUM(( COUNT(distinct prod_id) )) OVER() as total_item_count 

    from sales, customer, product
    where << conditions >>
    group by
        company_id  ,   prod_id
)
group by    
    sales_cases ,
    total_sales_cases ,
    total_item_count ,
    RowNbrCs ,
    company_id
order by  RowNbrCs desc
```